# How do I search partial words in Lucene when using MultiFieldQueryParser?

Tags: java, lucene

```
 public SearchResult search(String queryStr, SortBy sortBy, int maxCount)
      throws ParseException, IOException {
    String[] fields = {Indexer.TITLE_FIELD_NAME, Indexer.REVIEW_FIELD_NAME, "name"};


    QueryParser parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(fields, analyzer);
    Query query = parser.parse(queryStr);

    Sort sort = null;
    if (sortBy != null) {
        sort = sortBy.sort;
    }

    return searchAfter(null, query, sort, maxCount);
}
```

Above method just gives me the result, but for that I have to search for the whole word but if I search partial word it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `MultiFieldQueryParser` (and `QueryParser`, which this class inherits from) will look for the whole words you are searching, however it can also generate wildcard queries. The word "elephant" can be matched by using `elep*`, `elep?ant` (i.e. ? mathes a single letter) or `ele*nt`. You can also use fuzzy queries, like `elechant~`.

You can read the whole syntax specification here: http://lucene.apache.org/core/7_5_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html (below the class list).